# CLion doesn't index any external include paths

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Previously I've worked on the project using Eclipse. There, I'd import an xml file with `<includepath>` directories and `<macro>` defines into "paths/symbols" project settings and that would've been enough to index everything. I did a similar trick with VSCode and QtCreator, and it worked as well, but indexing was too slow compared to Eclipse.

Now I'm trying to import the same project into CLion. I'm not planning to build it, I only want the indexing to work. I've added all the local and external folders into the CMakeLists.txt using  `include_directories` and just copying all the paths from my Eclipse config. At first it wouldn't index anything at all. After I marked the "src" folder of my project as "Project Sources and Headers", it seems that now it indexes source/header links, but it still ignores anything specified in the CMakeLists file. How do I force CLion to index all of all the external include paths without actually building? Basically it's set up with mingw, and it's fine with using mingw gcc, g++ and make, and it just fails to do anything without showing any kinds of errors.

The current CMakeLists.txt file looks like...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(GRP)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/...") #hundreds of project dirs
...
include_directories("C:/Users/...") #hundreds of external includes
...
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your CMakeLists.txt file so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: @PaulB It's literally just the standard stuff

    `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)`
    `project(GRP)`

    `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`

And then nothing but several hundred `include_directories` in there.

Comment: Edit your question and add the content of your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Did you reload your cmake project? (Right-click on Project -> Reload CMake Project)

Comment: @ThomasSablik, Yes, it completes with no errors

Comment: Did you actually add an executable with [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html)?

In CMake `include_directories` just adds the directories so that they'll be included (with `-I` ) in each compiler invocation.

Comment: @PaulB No other IDE actually requires any executables to add. All it needs to do is to index the existing source/header files. I'm not trying to build it, I only need the indexing and the syntax check.

Comment: Try adding a dummy target with a single source file to see if that resolves it. Something like `add_executable(dummy dummy.cpp)` and make a file called `dummy.cpp` beside it.

Answer (score 1):

For me in this situation right-clicking on project and selecting **Reload CMake Project** solved the problem.